# Gitlab schema - Rails Postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, gitlab

Where do the comments of users get stored in the gitlab schema?
I tried accessing the following git repo:
https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/db/schema.rb
Yet I am unable to spot the comments field in any of the tables.

Answer (score 1):

Just figured out that the table was under the name 'notes' in the postgres schema. Also, I was looking at the master build, rather than the stable dev build of the schema. 
Here's the destination link, if anyone needs it.
https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/9-0-stable/db/schema.rb